# Is there a way to intercept or otherwise react to an outgoing XHR call from a JavaFX WebView?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to find out if there is a way that I could react to unexpected communication from within a WebView in JavaFX.  The end goal is to determine if we would be able to prompt the user when an HTML/JS file tries to make an unexpected XHR request to an unknown server.

The following HTML is loaded into a JavaFX WebView:

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendXHR() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    
    xhttp.open("GET", "<URL>", true);
    xhttp.send();   
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button onClick="sendXHR()">Test</button>
<p><b>Result:</b></p>
<p id="result"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The XHTTP request targets a simple endpoint that returns a string and the string is populated on the page after the request completes.  It's used to indicate that the request made it through and that I missed an opportunity to catch the request before it goes out.  The use case I'd want to block is less about the clicking of the button, but rather an action that might be triggered silently by a document.onLoad() event, so an event listener on "click" wouldn't address the next use case.

I have set up a breakpoint on the event listener to see if I could trip the debugger when I clicked the button, but the breakpoint only gets hit during the initial load of the page. It seems that once the document loads, control is handed over to Webkit for all but UI interactions.

Based on information from the [WebEngine javadoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html), I thought there might be a way to override the XMLHttpRequest object with a prompt function in JavaFX.

```
public class XMLHttpRequestInterceptor {

        // Tried with both no params and JSObject params to match the definitions here:    
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open
    public void open() {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            Alert a = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
            a.setTitle("Blocked");
            a.setHeaderText("Blocked");
            a.setContentText("XMLHttpRequest attempted");
            a.showAndWait();
        });
    }   
}
```

I can block the request by overriding the XMLHttpRequest object (not the instance) after the page loads.  Bad news: there is no way to make the block conditional; the open() function I included in the target object fails to get called when the Javascript calls XMLHttpRequest.open().

Is this something that is even plausible, or am I spinning my wheels?

JDK is 11, JavaFX version is 17.0.7